# What's wrong with accessing row in database from MainActivity?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to access a row in my database from MainActivity in the following fashion. I'd like to know a better way to do this since this crashes my app with the error every time. Even after cold rebooting and wiping data.

"23:06  Emulator: glTexImage2D: got err pre :( 0x502 internal 0x1908 format 0x1908 type 0x1401

I assume there is a better way to do this. I'm calling a method which takes a User object which is stored in my database presumably at index 1. (first place in database)

```
 if(myDb.isNotEmpty() == true) {
                    MyProgress.calculateBalance***(myDb.getUser(1));***
```

this is my getUser method.

```
public User getUser(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, // a. table
                COLUMNS, // b. column names
                " id = ?", // c. selections
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, // d. selections args
                null, // e. group by
                null, // f. having
                null, // g. order by
                null); // h. limit

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        User user = new User();
        user.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        user.setWeight (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
        user.setAge(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));

        return user;
    }
```

Comment: `this crashes my app` is not an error description; please add the relevant stack-trace... besides, calling `db.close()` is suggested (possibly even the reason for the crash).

Comment: that error message is GL drivers related... and has nothing to do with the code. the relevant stack-trace should refer to the `MainActivity` and have a bunch of lines; commonly displayed in red text.

Comment: I really can't find other error messages than that. The problem is however solved. It works since I wrapped my getUser method(). Are you saying I should call db.close in MainActivity?

Comment: Please note that `query()` always returns a `Cursor` or throws an error. So, wrap your code in a `try..catch` block and forget about `if(cursor != null)`. Also note that if you are returned a valid `Cursor` object that this does not mean that you have any values. This means that you should be checking the `boolean` value returned by `cursor.moveToFirst()` before you proceed with trying to read the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last part of your method should look like this:

```
if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    User user = new User();    
    user.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
    user.setWeight (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
    user.setAge(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
    return user;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

This code ensures that the if the cursor returned is `null` or does not contain at least 1 row, it will not throw an error.  
In this case the method will return `null`. 
Of course if the cursor is prepared with no errors and `myDB` is properly initialized there is no reason for the cursor to be null, so you must check for valid column, table and database names. 
Also after every change you make to any of these always uninstall the app from the emulator/device so the database is deleted and rerun the app to recreate everything.

Answer (score 1):

Better way would be use [Save data in a local database using Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/)

Here is your code I see null check is done but it protect only one statement from NPE. You need to wrap user creation under this if condition.

```
@Nullable
public User getUser(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, // a. table
            COLUMNS, // b. column names
            " id = ?", // c. selections
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, // d. selections args
            null, // e. group by
            null, // f. having
            null, // g. order by
            null); // h. limit

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       User user = new User();
       user.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
       user.setWeight (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
       user.setAge(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));

       return user;
   } 

   return null;
}
```